# Passing swift block to React Native

Tags: javascript, swift, react-native

Is it possible to pass block from Swift to React Native as prop? I'm trying to do:

```
    let rnRoot = RCTRootView(
        bundleURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios"),
        moduleName: "App",
        initialProperties: ["callLog": { (arg: String) in
            print(arg)
        }],
        launchOptions: nil
    )!
```

It seems to me, that callLog gets passed and even RN gets the idea, that it's function, logs are:

```
2018-01-14 12:28:11.650130+0100 prj[46427:1071345] Running application App ({
    initialProps =     {
        callLog = "(Function)";
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
```

But it starts with callLog as null anyway:

> Running application "App" with appParams:
>   {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{"callLog":null}}. **DEV** === true,
>   development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF

Is it possible to do that at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send a block of swift code directly as an initialProp. The bridge will not know how to interpret it. Any swift code that you want to call through JS must be done through a Native Module.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html